# Fullcalendar nowIndicator always in center

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

**Fullcalendar centered view based on the nowIndicator**

```
calendarOptions: {
  nowIndicator: true
}
```

Is it possible to 'always' center the timeline-view based on the `nowIndicator`?

Even with a slotMinTime set to 10:00 and a slotMaxTime set to 23:00?

Comment: Not really no because if now happens to be very near the start or end of the period the view covers then it cannot be scrolled far enough left or right to center the time, and as you say if now falls outside the visible times you've allowed on the view then there is no physical point on the calendar for it to centre on.

Answer (score 0):

In vue I found a solution to always (almost) center the view.
I used the calendar API with the scrollToTime function.

When calendar is loaded, I scroll to the current time.

(Possible) Solution (tested and worked):

```
    let cal = this.$refs.fullcalendar.getApi()
    let date = new Date()
    let currentTime = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2)-1 + ':'
            + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':'
            + '00';
    cal.scrollToTime(currentTime)
```